# How do I create a Solr core without creating the config file first?

Tags: solr

I am making a Solr web-based application and one of the features is the user can create a core and schema to the Solr. My friend made it using child process by going to the directory of the Solr first and then using the command 'bin/solr create -c...' the core can be created. But I am thinking of another approach, like using the http api request. I found this.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=mycore&instanceDir=path/to/instance&configSet=configset2
```

But apparently, it cannot run properly because you need to make the config file first for the core. The error says like this.

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'mycore': Unable to create core [mycore] Caused by: Could not load configuration from directory/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/configset2
```

So I am wondering what kind of approach I can do, since it seems like I can't make a core without setting up a config first. Or should I make an input menu with create core, create schema and only after the user clicks 'submit' it will process everything, from making a config file, creating schema, and then finally creating the core? I wonder if it's the best approach.
I am looking forward to any help.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to provide a configuration when creating a core.

When your friend run the command, it actually used the default configuration **data_driven_schema_configs**, which you can confirm by reading the explanation from **create_core** command (**create** is an alias for **create_core** for non Cloud setup):

```
bin/solr create_core -h
```

The solr script copied that configuration and then created the core with it.

The example you showed is only valid for SolrCloud. If you are not using SolrCloud, you need to be using [Core Admin API directly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE) and manually setup the directory with configuration.

Notice that configsets are a bit of a tricky thing in the sense that if you create several cores from the same configset, that configset is shared and changes made to it by one core affect all of them. So, you most likely don't want to use them, but instead copy the configuration as I described above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am now considering using the API directly like in the link you mentioned above. But I am not exactly sure how to get started. So, first I have to make the instanceDir and the config file right? How do I do that through API? Is there a way to do that? I only know through console. Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind, I finally found a way to create core through API. The documentation I found only gives hints on the Solr Cloud mode while I am on single core. Here is the API that works. `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=test_core&configSet=basic_configs`